# How to access fields of a JSON in GO

Tags: json, go, printing

Hi everyone I'm trying to see what the proper way of accessing fields of a json object from a http.get request in go.

I first do an http.get call get the JSON and then print it (which works) but is there a way to access just a field?

for example:

```
response, err:= http.Get("URL")
//Error checking is done between
contents, err:=ioutil.Readall(response.Body)

//Now at this point I have a json that looks like
{"id": "someID", 
"name": "someName", 
"test": [{"Name":"Test1", 
          "Result": "Success"},
         {"Name":"Test2", 
          "Result": "Success"},
         {...},
]}
```

Is there a way to only print the "test" of the Json? What is the proper way of accessing that field?

Comment: you will have to parse json using `encoding/json` package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `encoding/json` package to Unmarshal data into struct, like following.

```
type Result struct {
    ID   string        `json:"id"`
    Name string        `json:"name"`
    Test []interface{} `json:"test"`
}

var result Result
json.Unmarshal(contents, &result)
fmt.Println(result.Test)
```

You can also parse `Test` to specific struct.

Comment: Ohhh I see, what did you mean parse Test to a specific struct?

Comment: You can define a struct named Test and in Result struct use Test []Test instead of Test []interface{}

Comment: Struct fields that have a json tag (all of them, in the example proposed here) need to be exported, meaning they need to start with a capital letter. More info at [Exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)

Answer (score 12):

Same as the previous answer, use encoding/json package to Unmarshal data. But if you don't want to specify the structure, you could use map[string]interface/bson.M{} to receive the data, and get the field, then cast into types your want.

```
m := make(map[string]interface{})
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(m["id"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try gabs container, if you are not sure how depth JSON hierarchy can be. Have  a look at below  resources

https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs
https://godoc.org/github.com/Jeffail/gabs

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to access one field then you can use the jsonq module https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/jsonq

For your example you could get the test object with code similar to

```
jq.Object("test")
```

Where jq is a jsonq query object constructed from your JSON above (see the godoc page for instructions on how to create a query object from a JSON stream or string).

You can also use this library for retrieving specific String, Integer, Float and Bool values at an arbitrary depth inside a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are starting with a URL, `Decode` is a better option than `Unmarshal`:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get("https://github.com/manifest.json")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   var s struct { Name string }
   json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&s)
   println(s.Name == "GitHub")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json#Decoder.Decode

Answer (score 0):

You may check this https://github.com/valyala/fastjson

```
s := []byte(`{"foo": [123, "bar"]}`)
    fmt.Printf("foo.0=%d\n", fastjson.GetInt(s, "foo", "0"))

    // Output:
    // foo.0=123
```